# Finding closest mid-route add-in destination

Tags: google-maps

Is there any method in which I could setup a route from work to home:

1. `<workplace address>`
2. `<home address>`

and then add an additional location:

1. `<workplace address>`
2. 
3. `<home address>`

and search for specific type of location, such as park, supermarket, gas station, etcetera:

1. `<workplace address>`
2. supermarket
3. `<home address>`

to find the location which is least disruptive to my route, with traffic remaining factored in)?

**Example**:

Current attempts to search for **supermarket** (using Google Maps on Chrome browser on Windows PC) assume a specific supermarket without offering a selection.

(In my specific experiment, the automatically selected supermarket was immediately undesirable since it asks me to head away from my home rather than suggest a place which is on the way.)

Alternatives are available, using the link: `is this not the supermarket you were looking for?`.

Clicking this link lists several other alternative supermarkets (with addresses written in unselectable text), but when mouse-hovering over the alternatives, the route(s) to/through these locations (or even just a pin of the location) don't load up on the map; therefore you have to choose one blindly, with no recourse for comparison.

Opening the alternatives in a new tab is not supported.

Clicking any of the suggestions (blindly) also causes the user to (irrevocably) lose the search to the rest.

Clicking `back` shows the original, automatically-selected supermarket, but removes the link to show alternatives.

Additionally, reperforming the search tends to list the supermarkets in a different order, which leads the user toward losing track of which supermarkets have been attempted already.

Comment: Sometimes google maps decides to show alternatives, sometimes it picks one... google does what it wants. Open a new tab & search for alternatives, and pick the one closest to your route yourself, then put it's address into your main route tab... but you said you can't use a new tab, or you didn't try like this?

Answer (score 1):

This finds and adds a destination along your route. It does not solve the second problem mentioned later in your OP about not getting to choose from a list of destinations.

Create a route from Bellevue WA to Puyallup WA.

Click "+ Add destination."

Type "burgers near Burien" and Enter.

(Burien is a community along the route. It's the best Google can do.)

A specific Burien fast-food place is added to the end of the route after Puyallup. You must drag it up into the sequence position you want.

https://support.google.com/maps/forum/AAAAQuUrST8jF2ICrFUl-4?hl=en